# Buttons mystically disabled in Firefox, works in Chrome & IE

Tags: html, angularjs, firefox

I'm using AngularJS and in my view I have some buttons. In Chrome, and even IE it looks fine, however, in Firefox some of the buttons are disabled for some reason. In the image the left buttons are in Chrome and the right in Firefox. (Image here: http://tinypic.com/r/29p2f4y/8)

The first row is just three button, the second row the buttons are wrapped in a  element and in the third row the buttons are inside a  element.

Does anyone know why the buttons behave like this? I'm using Firefox 26.0.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Not really that fancy: 

<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>

<div>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="showMe">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>

Comment: What I meant was a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that shows the same behaviour as your problematic code while omitting everything that has no influence on said behaviour. With HTML-related problems [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is often used around here.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek, Tried to make a fiddle but I can't seem to trigger the problem from it. If I remove all of my code and replace it with the example code written above, then I have the same problem. Don't know why it doesn't occur in the fiddle..